# $G=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 | 1\leq x^2 + y^2\leq16 \text{ and } 0\leq x \text{ and }0\leq y \}$ Calculate $\underset{G}{\int\int}xy^2dxdy $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm making some exercises for my analysis exam, and i'm having trouble with this exercise.

$G=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 | 1\leq x^2 + y^2\leq16 \text{ and } 0\leq x \text{ and }0\leq y  \}$

Calculate $$\underset{G}{\int\int}xy^2dxdy $$

I think that:

$$\underset{G}{\int\int}xy^2dxdy = \int_0^{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi}\int_1^4 r^4 \cos \theta \sin \theta^2 dr d\theta $$

But I don't how to continue. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've got:
$$
\underset{G}{\int\int}xy^2dxdy = \int_0^{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi}\int_1^4 r^4 \cos \theta \sin^2 \theta dr d\theta = \int_1^4 r^4dr\int_0^1 u^2 du=
\left. \frac{r^5}{5}\right|_{r=1}^4 \, \left.\frac{u^3}{3}\right|_{u=0}^1=
\frac{4^5-1^5}{5}\frac{1-0}{3}=\frac{1023}{15},
$$
where I used the substitution $u=\sin \theta \Rightarrow du=\cos \theta d\theta$.

Comment: Why don't you get $\sin^2 (\sin \theta) $ ?

Comment: Edited the answer to be more clear.